# LCD not displaying text (16x2)

Tags: arduino-uno

[image]

(https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-based-accident-alert-system-using-gps-gsm-accelerometer)

the code is

```
Serial.println(zValue);
..... .....
........ ...
```

Here we have also created some other function for various purposes like `void gpsEvent()` to get GPS coordinates, `void coordinate2dec()` for extracting coordinates from the GPS string and convert them into Decimal values, `void show_coordinate()` for displaying values over serial monitor and LCD, and finally the `void Send()` for sending alert SMS to the predefined number.

Complete code and demo video is given below, you can check all the functions in the code.

Code

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial Serial1(2,3); //make RX arduino line is pin 2, make TX arduino line is pin 3.
SoftwareSerial gps(10,11);
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(4,5,6,7,8,9);

#define x A1
#define y A2
#define z A3

int xsample=0;
int ysample=0;
int zsample=0;

#define samples 10

#define minVal -50
#define MaxVal 50

int i=0,k=0;
int  gps_status=0;
float latitude=0; 
float logitude=0;                       
String Speed="";
String gpsString="";
char *test="$GPRMC";

void initModule(String cmd, char *res, int t)
{
  while(1)
  {
    Serial.println(cmd);
    Serial1.println(cmd);
    delay(100);
    while(Serial1.available()>0)
    {
       if(Serial1.find(res))
       {
        Serial.println(res);
        delay(t);
        return;
       }

       else
       {
        Serial.println("Error");
       }
    }
    delay(t);
  }
}

void setup() 
{
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16,2);  
  lcd.print("Accident Alert  ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("     System     ");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initializing");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Please Wait...");
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("Initializing....");
  initModule("AT","OK",1000);
  initModule("ATE1","OK",1000);
  initModule("AT+CPIN?","READY",1000);  
  initModule("AT+CMGF=1","OK",1000);     
  initModule("AT+CNMI=2,2,0,0,0","OK",1000);  
  Serial.println("Initialized Successfully");
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initialized");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Successfully");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Callibrating ");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Acceleromiter");
  for(int i=0;i<samples;i++)
  {
    xsample+=analogRead(x);
    ysample+=analogRead(y);
    zsample+=analogRead(z);
  }

  xsample/=samples;
  ysample/=samples;
  zsample/=samples;

  Serial.println(xsample);
  Serial.println(ysample);
  Serial.println(zsample);
  delay(1000);

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Waiting For GPS");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("     Signal    ");
  delay(2000);
  gps.begin(9600);
  get_gps();
  show_coordinate();
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("GPS is Ready");
  delay(1000);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("System Ready");
  Serial.println("System Ready..");
}

void loop() 
{
    int value1=analogRead(x);
    int value2=analogRead(y);
    int value3=analogRead(z);

    int xValue=xsample-value1;
    int yValue=ysample-value2;
    int zValue=zsample-value3;

    Serial.print("x=");
    Serial.println(xValue);
    Serial.print("y=");
    Serial.println(yValue);
    Serial.print("z=");
    Serial.println(zValue);

    if(xValue < minVal || xValue > MaxVal  || yValue < minVal || yValue > MaxVal  || zValue < minVal || zValue > MaxVal)
    {
      get_gps();
      show_coordinate();
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("Sending SMS ");
      Serial.println("Sending SMS");
      Send();
      Serial.println("SMS Sent");
      delay(2000);
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("System Ready");
    }       
}

void gpsEvent()
{
  gpsString="";
  while(1)
  {
   while (gps.available()>0)            //Serial incoming data from GPS
   {
    char inChar = (char)gps.read();
     gpsString+= inChar;                    //store incoming data from GPS to temparary string str[]
     i++;
    // Serial.print(inChar);
     if (i < 7)                      
     {
      if(gpsString[i-1] != test[i-1])         //check for right string
      {
        i=0;
        gpsString="";
      }
     }
    if(inChar=='\r')
    {
     if(i>60)
     {
       gps_status=1;
       break;
     }
     else
     {
       i=0;
     }
    }
  }
   if(gps_status)
    break;
  }
}

void get_gps()
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Getting GPS Data");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Please Wait.....");
   gps_status=0;
   int x=0;
   while(gps_status==0)
   {
    gpsEvent();
    int str_lenth=i;
    coordinate2dec();
    i=0;x=0;
    str_lenth=0;
   }
}

void show_coordinate()
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Lat:");
    lcd.print(latitude);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Log:");
    lcd.print(logitude);
    Serial.print("Latitude:");
    Serial.println(latitude);
    Serial.print("Longitude:");
    Serial.println(logitude);
    Serial.print("Speed(in knots)=");
    Serial.println(Speed);
    delay(2000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("Speed(Knots):");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(Speed);
}

void coordinate2dec()
{
  String lat_degree="";
    for(i=20;i<=21;i++)         
      lat_degree+=gpsString[i];

  String lat_minut="";
     for(i=22;i<=28;i++)         
      lat_minut+=gpsString[i];

  String log_degree="";
    for(i=32;i<=34;i++)
      log_degree+=gpsString[i];

  String log_minut="";
    for(i=35;i<=41;i++)
      log_minut+=gpsString[i];

    Speed="";
    for(i=45;i<48;i++)          //extract longitude from string
      Speed+=gpsString[i];

     float minut= lat_minut.toFloat();
     minut=minut/60;
     float degree=lat_degree.toFloat();
     latitude=degree+minut;

     minut= log_minut.toFloat();
     minut=minut/60;
     degree=log_degree.toFloat();
     logitude=degree+minut;
}

void Send()
{ 
   Serial1.println("AT");
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.println("AT+CMGF=1");
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.print("AT+CMGS=");
   Serial1.print('"');
   Serial1.print("9821757249");    //mobile no. for SMS alert
   Serial1.println('"');
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.print("Latitude:");
   Serial1.println(latitude);
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.print(" longitude:");
   Serial1.println(logitude);
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.print(" Speed:");
   Serial1.print(Speed);
   Serial1.println("Knots");
   delay(500);
   serialPrint();
   Serial1.print("http://maps.google.com/maps?&z=15&mrt=yp&t=k&q=");
   Serial1.print(latitude,6);
   Serial1.print("+");              //28.612953, 77.231545   //28.612953,77.2293563
   Serial1.print(logitude,6);
   Serial1.write(26);
   delay(2000);
   serialPrint();
}

void serialPrint()
{
  while(Serial1.available()>0)
  {
    Serial.print(Serial1.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make your code readable by putting it in a code block. Also reduce your code to what you need to examine your problem (which is trouble printing to the LCD display). All the other GPS/coordinate calculation code you've included is just noise at this moment. Also, it would be nice if you could include the image in your question instead of in a link. You mention a demo video but it's not there.

Comment: One more question: have you tried to adjust the LCD contrast with the potentiometer?

Comment: Can you see anything on the LCD?

Comment: @Ch Murali, Please answer our questions.